# how to enable PMU in KVM guest

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm

I am running KVM/QEMU in my Lenovo X1 laptop.

The guest OS is Ubuntu 15.04 x86_64.

Now, I want to run 'perf' command in guest OS, but I found followings in guest OS in dmesg.

...

[    0.055442] smpboot: CPU0: Intel Xeon E3-12xx v2 (Ivy Bridge) (fam: 06, model: 3a, stepping: 09)

[    0.056000] Performance Events: unsupported p6 CPU model 58 no PMU driver, software events only.

[    0.057602] x86: Booting SMP configuration:

[    0.058686] .... node  #0, CPUs:      #1

[    0.008000] kvm-clock: cpu 1, msr 0:1ffd6041, secondary cpu clock

...
So, the perf command could NOT work hardware PMU event in guest OS.

How could I enable hardware PMU from my host to the Ubuntu guest?

Thanks,

-Tao

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page https://github.com/mozilla/rr/wiki/Building-And-Installing gives some hints how to enable guest PMU:

> Qemu: On QEMU command line use
>
> ```
>  -cpu host
> ```
>
> Libvirt/KVM: Specify CPU passthrough in domain XML definition:
>
> ```
>  <cpu mode='host-passthrough'/>
> ```

Same advice in https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_tuning_and_optimization_guide/sect-virtualization_tuning_optimization_guide-monitoring_tools-vpmu

I edit `<cpu mode='host-passthrough'/>` line into `/etc/libvirt/qemu/my_vm_name.xml` file instead of `<cpu>...</cpu>` block.

(In virt-manager use "host-passthrough" as CPU "Model:" field - http://blog.wikichoon.com/2016/01/using-cpu-host-passthrough-with-virt.html)

Now PMU works, tested with `perf stat echo` inside the VM, there are "arch_perfmon" in `/proc/cpuinfo` and PMUs are enabled in `dmesg|grep PMU`.

`-cpu host` option of Qemu was used according to /var/log/libvirt/qemu/vm_name.log:

```
/usr/bin/kvm-spice ... -machine ...,accel=kvm,... -cpu host ...
```

Comment: Within the Ubuntu 20.04 host OS, setting 'host-passthrough' in guest.xml still can NOT enable PMU within guest.... I don't know why? And wonder if there is any other way to enable PMU for guest Linux? Thanks,