# Best way to test a custom kernel for hardware performance counters

Tags: docker, build, linux-kernel, virtual-machine, performancecounter

I would like to modify an official linux kernel to test some possibilities for perf linux module (I need to modify some files in kernel/events/..., not only tools/perf/...).

Naively, I though of using a VM or Docker but I need to test my custom version with hardware performance counters (HPC); and it's a big problem :

- Docker can take HPC but I understood but only by my host kernel, I can't test directly a custom kernel without installing it on my system (correct me if I am wrong)
- The VM can't take HPC because it can't emulate it

What is the best way to test a custom kernel linux without installing directly the kernel on my ubuntu system ? And if I have to, what is the most elegant way to do these tests ? Thank you.

Comment: Docker can't usefully be part of this picture, since it always shares the host kernel.  It has to be a virtual machine in some form.

Comment: You can install multiple kernels and just boot into yours for test.

Comment: Yes I think this is the wisest solution too. Thank you, if there is no other way, this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution : KVM + QEMU emulator.

To use PMU, I changed this parameter in the VM parameters (XML format)  :

```
<cpu mode='host-passthrough'/>
```

Or you can add this option in cmd line :

```
-cpu host
```

I followed in part this [page](https://offlinemark.com/2020/09/26/how-to-set-up-a-minimal-linux-kernel-dev-environment-on-ubuntu-20-04/) for building the kernel on qemu and for the counters this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490857/how-to-enable-pmu-in-kvm-guest).